# Interlinear Spacing in markdown

Tags: markdown, text-alignment, gitbook

For an assignment I am forced to write my report in markdown.
Digging in to markdown I learned that there's very little text-alignment support in markdown.

That's why I came here to ask you if it's possible to provide Interlinear spacing?
What I want to become is that, e.g. a Title page, has it's content centered in the very middle of the entire page, horizontally as well as vertically.

Is this possible? if so, how?
thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

*The following answer was posted before it was made clear that the question related to GitBook, so this is a generic Markdown answer.*

Markdown does not have the concept of 'pages' because it is a plain-text markup format, and the main focus of it is to be readable as-is, but easily convertible to HTML, which also does not have the concept of a 'page' in the traditional printed-document sense.  However, it is possible to control how the resultant HTML would look when printed (or saved as a PDF by a browser) by providing an appropriate stylesheet for the HTML to use.

**However,** it strikes me that if you're being asked to write your assignment in Markdown, the person assessing it is trying to let you forget about formatting and just concentrate on the content of your assignment.  If they're asking for a Markdown file as the final deliverable, then there's nothing you can do about the formatting—and I imagine that's what the person assessing it intended.

Having said that: for reference, as you asked, here are the steps you'd take if you wanted to use HTML and a print stylesheet…

1. Write your Markdown file.
2. Use a Markdown converter such as [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org) to turn this into HTML.
3. Write some print-specific CSS to go with the HTML (most Markdown conversion programs let you specify the path to a custom CSS file, so that it will automagically be referenced by the HTML file when it's created—meaning you don't need to add the `<link>` tag manually).
4. View the HTML in a browser that supports print style sheets and choose to either export the document as PDF, or print it.

Then you will have a PDF or printed document with the formatting you desire.  Here's some example print-specific CSS you could use, which puts a page-break before all `<h1>` elements (this doesn't do exactly what you asked for; it's just an example—the Pandoc documentation and various general references on CSS should be able to help with the rest, though vertical centring is still a bit tricky in CSS):

```css
@media print {
    h1 {
        page-break-before: always;
    }
}
```

You may need to vary this depending on the output of your Markdown converter.  Also, most markdown converters allow you to give some of your Markdown a custom CSS class, to allow for more sophisticated styling, e.g. the markdown

```
### A Heading {.green}
```

May be translated into the following HTML

```html
<h3 class="green">A Heading</h3>
```

You could then create a "green" CSS class and use that to style the `<h3>`. Again, check the Markdown converter's documentation.

As for what you can do with print stylesheets: [Smashing magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/tips-and-tricks-for-print-style-sheets/) has some other pretty cool techniques for print styling.  [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com) is a great reference, too.

Comment: I'm writing the assignment in GitBook, which does provide some emulation of pages, therefor it is possible to construct a title-page